# Initiating Github webook based on new branch creation called "Release-XXXX"

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-webhook

Does anyone know if you can trigger a webhook based on the github action of creating a new branch called

Release-xxxx     where XXXX can be anything? I only want to initiate this webhook on that new branch name.

Answer (score 0):

In general, GitHub webhooks cover a single large category of activities that you are then responsible for filtering.  In your case, you can install [a webhook to be notified when a new branch or tag is created](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#create) and then perform the filtering yourself.

GitHub doesn't perform the filtering for you because filtering is expensive and there are a lot of operations to notify about.  This is no different than reading an events stream API and having to select only the events that you're interested in.

Comment: Ya. So I think I'll just make the call and have the lambda function filter it. I think it's easier. Thank you.